# Strange characters in OSX Terminal

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, git

I am using Terminal in OSX to Git files to and from remote repositories.

Suddenly I notice that some Git commands and status responses are returned and contain strange characters in them, such as the Angstrom symbol, and the 'AE' symbol.

Is this a setting or configuration I can correct?

Comment: There are actually two Unicode characters that look like the Angstrom symbol: Å U+212B ANGSTROM SIGN and Å U+00C5 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE. Interestingly, the other character that you mention comes right after the latter: Æ U+00C6 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER AE. In what contexts are you seeing these characters? Which commands? What is the exact output? Are they restricted to particular bits of output? Commit messages? File names? Error messages? Do you have *i18n.commitEncoding* or *i18n.logOutputEncoding* set in your effective configuration?

Answer (score 4):

Try the [`reset`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/reset.1.html) command to restore the normal settings for your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not in front of a Mac right now, but try

stty sane

That should restore some sanity to your terminal settings if they have been corrupted.