# Mac OS X Terminal, shows special characters like slash, space etc as strange character codes after using localedef

Tags: macos, terminal

I have recently used `localedef` command to add support for the multiple locales. After doing that I noticed on my terminal for every space, backslash, forward slash etc… it is instead showing UTF code like `<0200>` `<002d>` etc.

I really want to disable this behavior as it is really difficult to read commands.

For more clarity please see attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Same issue here after entering the command `cd /usr/share/locale/ && sudo localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8`, I was trying to fix a locale env issue in ssh sessions, now special character "é" for example is displayed as "<00c3><00a9>" in Terminal. The issue is only in the prompt display, I can see the chars in text editors, cat command etc.
locale env seems good though:
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=

Any idea what happened ?

Comment: Issue has been caused due to localedef I am able to confirm post getting a reply from Apple Support team.

As per the support team instruction I created a New User Account and checked terminal. With new account terminal worked well.

Best solution is  New User Account if we want avoid any manual effort. Otherwise you should compare ENV variables of Old account and New account and fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Ok it was a Terminal issue. Somehow localedef messed up the terminal config. `stty sane` fixed it for the Terminal app. And `defaults delete com.googlecode.iterm2`fixed it for iTerm.

Jamie's answer here [Strange characters in OSX Terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/209026/strange-characters-in-osx-terminal) helped me. (I can not upvote because I gave all my reputation for the bounty).

Edit: seems to be related to the fact that the terminal settings in Profiles > Advanced > "Set locale environment variables on startup" as unchecked.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @joucks and yes was an issue with the terminal and I have replied on it on my another stackoverflow question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357550/issue-with-mac-osx-terminal-shows-special-character-codes-like-space-brakets